# JDBC URL / Oracle RAC Server

Tags: oracle, jdbc, datasource

While I'm trying to connect my application to an existing Oracle RAC database. After doing some testing, we saw that my app was only connecting to one instance of the DB.
The original jdbc url is like:

> jdbc:oracle:thin@//yourhostname.com:1521/SID

The DBA provided some info that showed the connection were not in failover mode.
After some reading up on the forums it appears that the url needs to be changed, adding in TNS settings. So I ended up with the following :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin@(DESCRIPTION =(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS =
(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=scan-alias)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))
```

However when i start the app I get an oracle exception, 'NL Exception'
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a colon ':' before '@'.

Try this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=scan-alias)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=servicename)))
```

Note that I removed the extra ' ' space character as well that you had after 'DESCRIPTION='.

Comment: @dazednconfused please accept the answer if it addresses your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AS intimated by Jean deLavarene

May  You need to add a colon ':' before '@'  In addition u can add :FAILOVER_MODE and RETRIES parameter finally URL be like as follows.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=scan-alias)
(PORT=1521))(LOAD_BALANCE=ON)(FAILOVER=ON)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=SHARED)(SERVICE_NAME=FOODB)
(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=180)(DELAY=5))))
```

please go through Configuration of data source mentioned in below URL's:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigDataSources
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HABPT/config_fcf.htm